# C# Adressing multiple variables using a for()

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have this code:

```
cpMythic0.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.M0;
```

and let's say I have 31 cpMythic (string) variables all being named "cpMythic0, cpMythic1, cpMythic2 ... cpMythic30 and the same goes with some Properties Settings string variables called "M0,M1,M2...M30"

Instead of writing this:

```
cpMythic0.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.M0;
cpMythic1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.M1;
```

I would like to use a for() function, with an i variable but I don't really know the syntax.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use an array or list, don't create 30 separate variables.

Comment: Ok let's say I have a cpMythic[i] array then but how do I write the "Properties.Settings.Default.Mi code?

Comment: You don't. You use lists/arrays on both sides instead of separate variables. Thus the line would become something like `cpMythic[i] = Properties.Settings.Default.M[i];`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but this is achievable using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Fill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string propertyMatcher = "cpMythic";

            var defaultSettings = new Properties.Settings.Default(); //Get instance of default settings
            var settingProperties = defaultSettings.GetType().GetFields(); //Get default setting properties.

            foreach (TextBox control in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("cpMythic"))) //Loop through controls, and filter
            {
                string settingPropertyName = "M" + control.Name.Substring(propertyMatcher.Length);

                var settingProperty = settingProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == settingPropertyName);

                var value = settingProperty.GetValue(defaultSettings); //Get the value of the corresponding setting using reflection

                control.Text = value.ToString(); //Set value
            }
        }

        private static class Properties
        {

            public static class Settings
            {

                public class Default
                {
                    public string M0 = "Default Value 0";
                    public string M1 = "Default Value 1";
                    public string M2 = "Default Value 2";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you might do this if you were trying to build a UI to show the application settings... Its probably much simpler to just use a `PropertyGrid` control, which uses reflection to achieve the same result.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I assumed that is what they were trying to do, build a UI. This should work with what he currently has, if my assumption is correct. It demonstrates how Reflection can be used, and based on that, he can make his decision.